# Action bar is not hiding completely

Tags: android, android-actionbar

am tying to hide my action bar in runtime when i switch from tab2 to tab1 or tab3 but its leaving a blank space

my Activity: (with a TabLayout and 3 fragments )

[image]

switched to another tab , action bar is hidden now but there's a Blank space :

[image]

am using `actionBar.hide` / `actionBar.show` ,  any clue how to properly remove this extra space ???  if what am trying to achieve is not possible then please guide me to any alternative way

Codes:

```
ActionBar actionBar;
........
........
actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
........
........
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                if (tab == tab2){
                    actionBar.show();


                }else {
                    actionBar.hide();

                }};
```

Added Xml Codes:

MainActivity which includes  `content_main`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="MainActivity"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e4e4e4"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fillViewport="false"
    android:clickable="false" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @SathishKumarJ please check the updated question

Comment: @DixitPanchal please check the updated question

Answer (score 1):

Try this @ where you want to hide/show ActionBar,

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

// delaying the hiding of the ActionBar
Handler h = new Handler();
h.post(new Runnable() {     
    @Override
    public void run() {
        getActionBar().hide();//OR
        //getActionBar().show();
    }
});
```

> If Activity

```
getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
or 
getActionBar().hide();
```

> If Fragment

```
getActivity().getSupportActionBar().hide();
or
getActivity().getActionbar().hide();
```

Comment: hey @Sathish thanks for responding ,  well  `h.post` here post causing an error `cannot resolve method` and `Handler` is showing an error `Handler is abstract  cannot be instantiated` and forcing me to implement methods

Comment: `Handler h = new Handler() {
                @Override
                public void close() {
                    
                }

                @Override
                public void flush() {

                }

                @Override
                public void publish(LogRecord record) {

                }
            };
            h.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getActionBar().hide();//OR
                    //getActionBar().show();
                }
            });`

Comment: use import android.os.Handler;

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: now it showing a even bigger space after hiding the Action bar :D

Answer (score 1):

In my fragments this is how I hide the `ActionBar` and it works perfectly fine

```
// MainActivity is the activity which contains fragment
ActionBar actionBar = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
```

Comment: bro its hiding the actionBar but still its leaving the unWanted space

Comment: can you post the xml in which your setting up `TabLayout`?

Answer (score 0):

xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.myNoActionBarTheme">
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".NoticeboardActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.myNoActionBarTheme"></activity>
```